# Javascript stop drag event for panorama photos

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag

I've built a simple panorama photo viewer in jquery, see live example here:
http://alafiariver.org/alafia/view/aldermans-ford

How can I prevent this from being dragged too far? These photos vary in width, so the solution needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use containment property to restrict movement of image. See live example [here](http://jsbin.com/uqasu4/edit).